# How do *you* use auto_increment_increment?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Re: MySQL's global configuration option [auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment).

Other than

1. multi-master/circular replication in conjunction with [auto_increment_offset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset)
2. artificially "beefing up" stats when user/object id's are visible to the end users

**How/Why have you seen `auto_increment_increment` used in practice?**

Comment: In response to #2, a better way to do that is to assign and use a alternate and unique number, like a guid or pseudo-such, for externally-facing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just provide control, it's not used widely, it will allow if i need keys to be like this 10, 20, 30, etc

So i can insert records in between those records, like now i can insert 11,12,13 records (**later**) in between 10 and 20, which might be helpful in rarest case